# knockout condition in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Below is my HTML binding to display the records. I, have apply knockout js to perform the condition check as you can see the IF statement.

I want to use count++ as a knockout variable and perform the condition check.
The above code also not working for me.

Please can anyone let me know how to check the condition in knockout.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: GuidelinesQuestionList" id="problemcollapse">
                <div data-bind="foreach: $data.SectionsSet">
                    <div class="primaryCaseContainer">
                        <div class="questionHeader" data-bind="text: $data.Heading , attr:{onClick: 'variableName.CollapseExpandCustom.ToggleSection(\''+$data.Uid.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')+'\')'}"></div>
                        <div data-bind="attr: {id: $data.Uid.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')}">
                            @{int count = 0;}
                            <div class="questionContainer" data-bind="foreach: $data.ProblemsSet">

                                <div data-bind="if: $data.Identified">
                                    @{count++;}
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="" data-bind="text: $data.Text , click: $root.ProblemClick , attr:{id: $data.Id,Uid: $data.Uid , Rid: $data.Uid.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')}"></a>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <div data-bind="attr: {id: 'goalsReplaceDiv'+$data.Uid.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')}"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            @if (count == 0)
                            {
                                <div id="divNoRecordsMessage">
                                    <div>No Records !! </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: a simple way to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26227/ . hope it helps

Comment: Thanks super cool it worked for me

Comment: @xec computed is not necessarily needed here(IMHO) as you can save load time . the scenario works even with observables check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26232/ . as we know even you modify(delete etc) complete array is re-binded/readjusted . i may be missing something you saying please fork the fiddle and explain where it fails .

Comment: @supercool sorry! It appears I was mistaken (i will remove my comments) Basically, I did not expect this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26238/ (the `check()` seems to be run each time a `Identified` is changed, but it has nothing to do with the array itself being observable)

Comment: @supercool By the way, your assumption that the entire array is re-binded whenever one item changes (or removed or added etc) is wrong; see http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26240/

Comment: @xec yes thanks for correcting me i know internally its illogical to even think like that(re-binds) but i haven't given a thought .cheers mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing C# razor code with Knockout bindings. The `count` variable will not increment in your loop because it's evaluated before being returned to the client. Your loop is being rendered on the client.

Instead of doing that, make your `divNoRecordsMessage` show/hide based on a KO binding.

Something like this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: conditionForNoRecords">
  No Records
</div>
```

But you should really make a custom filter for the `ProblemSet` array, something like this:

```
self.filteredProblemsSets = ko.computed(function() {    
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.ProblemsSet(), function(item) {
        return item.Identified;
    });    
}, viewModel);
```

You could then skip your if condition in the view and you would be able to easily display "No messages" when the array is empty.

Comment: The length wont be zero. So, i need to check the variable count. the logic is like that

Comment: You'll need to put in your condition that determines if it should be visible or not

Comment: With the filteredProblemSets you can simply do `<div data-bind="visible: filteredProblemSets().length < 1">No Records</div>`  -- Note that there is no need to prepend with `$data.` as it is implied.